# Javascript function call

Tags: javascript

I have HTML element written like as follows

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" a="10" b="10" onclick="add(a,b)" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
```

Assume a function like this

```
function add(p1, p2) {
    return p1 + p2;              // The function returns the sum of p1 and p2
}
```

See in the above code I am calling one function add numbers (assume a simple add function), where I am declaring and passing values in the same line.

My question: 
    In real time I am supposed to do certain function call (declaring variables during element definition) as I mentioned above, How Browsers Reacts **majorly IE and Chrome?**
Will Both Browsers work the same way?

Comment: Is your question whether all browser interpret JavaScript the same?

Comment: function add(p1, p2) {
         return p1 + p2;              // The function returns the sum of p1 and p2
    }

Comment: Why wouldn't they do the same?

Comment: Please give your question a title which describes what you're asking.

Comment: They will probably give you slight variations on the errors you will get because that code won't work in any of them.

Comment: All browsers will throw an error when clicking on the checkbox, unless you have defined `a` and `b` somewhere in an earlier script. You'd need `this.a` and `this.b`, but custom attributes are deprecated, maybe obsoleted in some browsers. You can store data in HTML elements by using [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) though. Also you might get unexpected results, since all values of the attributes are strings.

Answer (score 4):

Change the HTML to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" data-a="10" data-b="10" onclick="add(this)" value="Bike">
```

and your JavaScript code:

```
function add(element) {
  a = +element.getAttribute('data-a');
  b = +element.getAttribute('data-b');
  alert(a + b);
}
```

according to HTML5 spec, to defining custom attribute you should prefix with `data-`

Comment: what are `+` for? This seems like the best answer so far, but I think OP is asking about browser support.

Comment: + is a shortcut for converting number string, e.g. `"15"` or `"32.7"` to number, where `parseInt` can parse those with unit e.g. `"24px"`

Comment: The `+` converts it to a number (could be anything, String, Object, Array, Null, ...). But it's not realy necessary here.

Comment: @CodeiSir Not necessary? OP says that they want to return a sum, not `"1010"` ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work on any browsers, this would:

```js
window.add = function (a, b) {
  a = parseInt(a, 10);
  b = parseInt(b, 10);
  alert(a + b);
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" a="10" b="10" onClick="window.add(this.getAttribute('a'),this.getAttribute('b'))" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
```

In your example `a` and `b` would either be undefined or not what you'd expect. You need to explicitly get the attributes of the current element (this when on a onClick handler). If the attribute is a known element's property, you can access it a bit easier like :

`this.src` for image elements, but since you're using non-standard attributes you can't do this.

---

You might want to be careful with defining your own custom attributes unless you namespace them and to be future-proof prepend them with `data-`.

So in your case:

`<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" data-xyz-a="10" data-xyz-b="10"...`

---

Be careful with the global scope inline javascript things, they are really really hard to manage at scale.

Answer (score 0):

That code won't work in any browsers. They will give the same error but likely report on it differently.

To improve your code implement HTML5 data attributes to contain the information you need and grab the information from the function.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" data-a="10" data-b="10" onclick="add(this)" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
```

JS

```
function add(el) {

  // + does a quick string to integer coercion
  var a = +el.dataset.a;
  var b = +el.dataset.b;
  return a + b;
}
```

Note, while you are actually returning the value of `a` and `b`, you're not really returning it *to* anywhere. Just an observation...

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8o5ar8z5/13/)

**You could also do this**, separating the JS from the HTML (*recommended*):

HTML

```
<input id="bike" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" data-a="10" data-b="10"  value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
```

JS

```
var bike = document.getElementById('bike');

bike.onclick = add;

function add() {
  var a = +el.dataset.a;
  var b = +el.dataset.b;
  return a + b;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8o5ar8z5/15/)